# Expected number of coin flips until number of tails equals number of heads

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Here is a simple probability question: An unfair coin with probability of heads equals $p$ is flipped once and lands heads. Compute the expected number of flips until the number of heads equals the number of tails.

The expected number of coin flips to get a tail is 1/(1-p) since it follows a geometric distribution. How to use this to answer the question? Does it have anything to do with catalan numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the Gambler's Ruin problem, with a starting bankroll of 1 dollar.  You want expected time until bankruptcy.  There are many solutions on this site.  Also there is a nice treatment in chapter 12 of Grinstead and Snell's free book https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Using linearity of expectation,

$1 + np = n(1-p) \implies n = \frac{1}{1-2p}$

Where $n$ is additional flips after the first.

And given you have the first landing as a head, we need $p \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

Another way to look at it -

I am starting with a difference of $1$ ($1$ head more than tail). So if it takes me $n$ flips to bridge that gap,

$n = 1 + p \times (n + n) \implies n = \frac{1}{1-2p}$ (I either bridge that gap with probability $(1-p)$ or I increase the gap by $1$ with probability $p$).

Comment: @nicomezi I do not think your expression is correct. The reason is this - you are choosing $L$ out of $2L$ flips. But that will have many arrangements where you reach the equal number of heads and tails much earlier. $2L$ has to be the number of flips where you reach equal number of H and T for the first time.

Comment: This is true ! However that does not prove your result but may be thats just me since I have problems with this exercise apparently ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MathLover but I'm afraid I don't understand it. Where exactly is the linearity of expectations used in the first approach? Also, where you write 'I either bridge that gap with probability $(1−)$ or I increase the gap by 1 with probability $$', I don't see a $1-p$ in the expression. Could you pls elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: OK I see now. So to your first question, what is the expected number of H in a flip? It is $p$ and for T, it is $(1-p)$ and this expectation is linear for every flip. So in $n$ flips after the first flip which is H, expected number of H = $1 + np$ and expected number of  T = $n(1-p)$.

Comment: On the second, it is the same thing as first but you are just thinking about it differently.  If we are taking $n$ flips, every flip the gap increases by $1$ with probability $p$ and reduces with probability $(1-p)$ and so the increase in gap and decrease in gap are equal after $n$ flips. So $0 = 1 + np - (n-np)$ or $n = 1 +  p (n + n)$